# data binding between two select angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have to select values in angular. I would like to connect two selects such as when I set the value of on the value of the other changes, too.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option selected>--Sélectionnez--</option>
    <option  *ngFor="let item of names"[ngValue]="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
     <option selected>--Sélectionnez--</option>
     <option *ngFor="let item of names ; let i = index">{{i}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call a change event like below

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option selected>--Sélectionnez--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of names" [ngValue]="item">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

where onChange is a function in your typescript file and set the values for the other select (here, with id exampleFormControlSelect2) option.

```
onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
}
```